# Batch transfer thousands of photos from iPhone

Tags: iphone, photos, preview

I am trying to transfer many thousands of photos from an extremely full iPhone. I am using "Import from iPhone" in Preview.app (open to other methods as well), but this method opens a preview "page" for every imported photo. Over time, this slows the process down and eventually crashes Preview.app once memory is exhausted.

Is there any way to avoid opening each image as it imports? I typically just close the preview window every few minutes, which does not affect the import, but it seems stupid to need to do this, especially for a multi-hour process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the solution here is to use "Image Capture", *not* Preview.app